# How to calculate effective amount from two amounts of different granularity?

Tags: sql-server, database-design, ssas

We have two table sources in MSSQL2008R2 database:

```
DAILY_SRC
    DAILY_SRC_ID int, primary key
    DATE datetime
    DAILY_AMOUNT decimal (39,18)
RAW_SRC
    RAW_SRC_ID int, primary key
    DAILY_SRC_ID int, foreign key
    DATE_AND_TIME datetime
    RAW_AMOUNT decimal (39,18)
    <other fields/dimensions are skipped>
```

Sum of amounts when grouped by DAILY_SRC_ID should be equal but they differ slightly.

DAILY _AMOUNT is taken as a correct one, so what we are doing on SQL side is calculating EFFECTIVE_RAW_AMOUNT by this procedure:

1. Add RAW_AMOUNT_SUM and CORRECTION_RATIO to DAILY_SRC
2. SET DAILY_SRC.RAW_AMOUNT_SUM = Sum(RAW_SRC.RAW_AMOUNT) BY DAILY_SRC_ID
3. Set DAILY_SRC.CORRECTION_RATIO = DAILY_SRC.RAW_AMOUNT_SUM / DAILY_SRC.RAW_AMOUNT_SUM (there are no zero values)
4. Add EFFECTIVE_AMOUNT to RAW_SRC
5. Update RAW_SRC.EFFECTIVE_AMOUNT = RAW_AMOUNT * CORRECTION_RATIO

Now DAILY_AMOUNT equals Sum(EFFECTIVE_AMOUNT) when grouped by DAILY_SRC_ID.

RAW_SRC is a fact table mapped to the cube, DAILY_SRC is a dimension.

The problem that this EFFECTIVE_AMOUNT calculation is being done on millions records (slow) and it prevents incremental processing of the cube, so we each time we have to load a whole day of records.

How this EFFECTIVE_AMOUNT calculation can be implemented in SSAS (as formula, or calculation or whatever)?

Comment: You could include the logic in a UDF and make it a computed column in your fact table.

Comment: Question isn't really clear. Could you include some sample data for 1  DAILY_SRC_ID. Why are the totals slightly different in the first place? What are these amount; money,inventory?

Comment: Why are the totals different? If one is wrong, why don't you fix the data rather than kludge it? Or if you know that one is right and one is wrong, why not just use the one that's right? Why do you have the same data stored twice anyway? If one is known to be wrong, why not just delete it and use the other?

Comment: UDF will be slow. Sample data is millions of records. Those records are call data records: daily ones are those we receive from satellite internet operator; raw amounts are those we measure on our network equipment. Our side measurement is not accurate - average difference is 5-10%. Amount is megabytes. As we do detailed reports for clients using our data, we have to adjust our data in a way that totals will match amounts they will have in their monthly invoices.

Comment: Straight SQL as described above takes 2-3 hours on up to 105 million records. Optimized SQL (a bit complex to describe) takes up to 20 minutes when we break data on 500 000 records batches. Also optimized SQL is not 100% correct as we throw away some boundary cases for the sake of speed.